# R - work on data frame rows based on condition

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I'm trying to understand how can I work on the rows of a data frame based on a condition.
Having a data frame like this

```
> d<-data.frame(x=c(0,1,2,3), y=c(1,1,1,0))
> d
  x y
1 0 1
2 1 1
3 2 1
4 3 0
```

how can I add +1 to all rows that contain a value of zero? (note that zeros can be found in any column), so that the result would look like this:

```
  x y
1 1 2
2 1 1
3 2 1
4 4 1
```

The following code seems to do part of the job, but is just printing the rows where the action was taken, the number of times it was taken (2)...

```
> for(i in 1:nrow(d)){
+     d[d[i,]==0,]<-d[i,]+1
+ }
> d
  x y
1 1 2
2 4 1
3 1 2
4 4 1
```

I'm sure there is a simple solution for this, maybe an apply function?, but I'm not getting there.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to display the changed row alone and also do you require to display it before adding 1 or after ? If its before I can write a simple code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some possibilities:

```
# 1
idx <- which(d == 0, arr.ind = TRUE)[, 1]
d[idx, ] <- d[idx, ] + 1
# 2
t(apply(d, 1, function(x) x + any(x == 0)))
# 3
d + apply(d == 0, 1, max)
```

The usage of `which` for vectors, e.g. `which(1:3 > 2)`, is quite common, whereas it is used less for matrices: by specifying `arr.ind = TRUE` what we get is array indices, i.e. coordinates of every 0:

```
which(d == 0, arr.ind = TRUE)
     row col
[1,]   1   1
[2,]   4   2
```

Since we are interested only in rows where zeros occur, I take the first column of `which(d == 0, arr.ind = TRUE)` and add 1 to all the elements in these rows by `d[idx, ] <- d[idx, ] + 1`.

Regarding the second approach, `apply(d, 1, function(x) x)` would be simply going row by row and returning the same row without any modifications. By `any(x == 0)` we check whether there are any zeros in a particular row and get `TRUE` or `FALSE`. However, by writing `x + any(x == 0)` we transform `TRUE` or `FALSE` to 1 or 0, respectively, as required.

Now the third approach. `d == 0` is a logical matrix, and we use `apply` to go over its rows. Then when applying `max` to a particular row, we again transform `TRUE`, `FALSE` to 1, 0 and find a maximal element. This element is 1 if and only if there are any zeros in that row. Hence, `apply(d == 0, 1, max)` returns a vector of zeros and ones. The final point is that when we write `A + b`, where `A` is a matrix and `b` is a vector, the addition is column-wise. In this way, by writing `d + apply(d == 0, 1, max)` we add `apply(d == 0, 1, max)` to every column of `d`, as needed.

Comment: ok, so the answer was not so simple (at least for me...). Can you elaborate on each function?

Comment: @PedroA For simplicity I would suggest `idx = d$x == 0 | d$y ==0; d[idx, ] = d[idx, ] + 1`.  It is similar to option 1, however, I feel it is a bit cleaner.  IMO, I would only consider option 1.  Option 2 and 3, while clever, are probably going to be slower than option 1 for larger matrices.  In general, it is best to approach R problems using sub-setting rather than iteration when possible.